# Check if value of an array is present in another array

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to check if value of an array *$spam* is present in array *$get_mail*.
I have following code, but it doesnt seem to work or I dont understand it properly.

```
$spam_exists = !array_diff($spam, $get_mail);

if ($spam_exists !== FALSE) { ... }
```

Any idea why this doesnt work?
Thank you for any reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [array_intersect](http://www.php.net/array_intersect) function.

```
$result = array_intersect($spam, $get_mail);
```

Which will return the values in both arrays as an array, or an empty array if there are no shared results.

So rather than using `!array_diff($X,$Y)` you could use `!empty(array_intersect($X,$Y))` or simply `if(array_intersect($X,$Y))`